# Bind hidden-field value to code behind field in Razor pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a hidden field on my Razor page that I append values of users to using javascript every time the principal user drags and drops a user into the "avoid" container. (this is meant to be a team builder app).

`<input id="AvoidPseudoList" type="hidden" aria-valuetext="" asp-for="AvoidPseudoList" >`

The javascript is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            const avoid = document.getElementById("avoidContainer");
            const avoidInput=document.getElementById("AvoidPseudoList");
            
            for(const child of avoid.children)
            {
                console.log(child);
                avoidInput.ariaValueText+=" "+child.innerHTML;
            }
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function () {
                
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public string AvoidPseudoList{get;set;}
```

When I console.log the hidden value, I can see that it's successfully appending users to the ariaValueText property, however when debugging, the code behind AvoidPseudoList is still set to null.

The full code for `TeamBuilderStudent.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model StudyBuddy.Pages.TeamBuilder.TeamBuilderStudentsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"]="Team Builder for Students";
}

<div class="container">
    <form method="Post">
        <h1>Welcome @User.Identity.Name </h1>
        <p>When is your preferred time to work?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="M"> Morning <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="A"> Afternoon <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="E"> Evening <br>

        <p>Select students that you would like to work with</p>
       @* <select name="preferred" class="preferred">
            <option value="">Select a classmate</option>
            @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
            {
                <option value=@classmate.UserName>@classmate.UserName</option>
            }
        </select>
        <br>
         <p>Select students that you want to avoid</p>
        <select name="avoid">
            <option value="">Select a classmate</option>
            @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
            {
                <option value=@classmate.UserName>@classmate.UserName</option>
            }
        </select> *@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Avoid</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h2>Student List</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h2>Prefer</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col containerD" id="avoidContainer">
                
                
            </div>

            <div class="col containerD">
                        @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
                        {
                            <p class="draggable" draggable="true">@classmate.UserName</p>
                        }
            </div>

            <div class="col containerD" id="prefer">
            </div>
        </div>
        

        <input id="AvoidPseudoList" type="hidden" aria-valuetext="" asp-for="AvoidPseudoList" >


        <br>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update Preferences</button>
    </form>
        
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            const avoid = document.getElementById("avoidContainer");
            const avoidInput=document.getElementById("AvoidPseudoList");
            
            for(const child of avoid.children)
            {
                console.log(child);
                avoidInput.ariaValueText+=" "+child.innerHTML;
            }
            console.log(avoidInput);
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function () {
                
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
        const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.containerD')

        draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
            draggable.classList.add('dragging')
        })

        draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
            draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
        })
        })

        containers.forEach(container => {
        container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)
            const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
            if (afterElement == null) {
            container.appendChild(draggable)
            } else {
            container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
            }
        })
        })

        function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
        const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

        return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
            const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
            const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
            if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
            } else {
            return closest
            }
        }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
        }
    </script>
}
    
</div>
```

The full code for `TeamBuilderStudent.cshtml.cs`:

```
@page
@model StudyBuddy.Pages.TeamBuilder.TeamBuilderStudentsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"]="Team Builder for Students";
}

<div class="container">
    <form method="Post">
        <h1>Welcome @User.Identity.Name </h1>
        <p>When is your preferred time to work?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="M"> Morning <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="A"> Afternoon <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AreChecked" value="E"> Evening <br>

        <p>Select students that you would like to work with</p>
       @* <select name="preferred" class="preferred">
            <option value="">Select a classmate</option>
            @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
            {
                <option value=@classmate.UserName>@classmate.UserName</option>
            }
        </select>
        <br>
         <p>Select students that you want to avoid</p>
        <select name="avoid">
            <option value="">Select a classmate</option>
            @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
            {
                <option value=@classmate.UserName>@classmate.UserName</option>
            }
        </select> *@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Avoid</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h2>Student List</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <h2>Prefer</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col containerD" id="avoidContainer">
                
                
            </div>

            <div class="col containerD">
                        @foreach (var classmate in Model.UserList)
                        {
                            <p class="draggable" draggable="true">@classmate.UserName</p>
                        }
            </div>

            <div class="col containerD" id="prefer">
            </div>
        </div>
        

        <input id="AvoidPseudoList" type="hidden" aria-valuetext="" asp-for="AvoidPseudoList" >


        <br>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update Preferences</button>
    </form>
        
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            const avoid = document.getElementById("avoidContainer");
            const avoidInput=document.getElementById("AvoidPseudoList");
            
            for(const child of avoid.children)
            {
                console.log(child);
                avoidInput.ariaValueText+=" "+child.innerHTML;
            }
            console.log(avoidInput);
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function () {
                
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
        const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.containerD')

        draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
            draggable.classList.add('dragging')
        })

        draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
            draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
        })
        })

        containers.forEach(container => {
        container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)
            const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
            if (afterElement == null) {
            container.appendChild(draggable)
            } else {
            container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
            }
        })
        })

        function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
        const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

        return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
            const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
            const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
            if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
            } else {
            return closest
            }
        }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
        }
    </script>
}
    
</div>
```

Any idea what I should be doing to properly bind the values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna bind value from your page to backend, You can add `value` attribute in your `<input />` tag. You need `value` attribute to bind the value of `input`

```
<input id="AvoidPseudoList" type="hidden" aria-valuetext="" value="" asp-for="AvoidPseudoList" >
```

in `Js` code, You can add code:

```
//..........
for(const child of avoid.children)
{
      console.log(child);
      avoidInput.ariaValueText+=" "+child.innerHTML;
      avoidInput.value +=" "+child.innerHTML;
}
//.........
```

Then you can bind the value in your backend.

[image]

Comment: HI@SpicyRiceTea, If this answer can solve your issue, Can you accept it as the answer?[how to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thank you very much!